# Photo returns to original position after being dragged to new position

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app

According to a web search, I should be able to drag a photo into a new position in the Photos app that is native to iPhone.

When I do that, the thumbnail moves when I drag, but when I release, it simply moves back to its original position.  At no point do the photos rearrange themselves to accommodate the new position of the dragged photo.

What am I doing wrong?  I have the iPhone SE.  According to
`Settings->General->About`, the iPhone is running iOS 14.4

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?  I'm not able to rearrange photos by dragging, I get the same result as you (iOS 15.2).

Comment: I found the same instructions at multiple places: https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+photo+change-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this for albums, not Library (And only for albums you've created, not auto-generated ones like 'Recents').

To rearrange photos in an album: Tap Library button in bottom toolbar, select any album from "My Albums"; press on a photo thumbnail, drag it to the desired place and release. It will stay there.

Library is always presented in Date/Time order.

Comment: I went to `Albums->My Albums->Recents` and tried dragging.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.  I get the same behaviour as in my originally posted question.

Comment: This works with user-created albums, not auto-generated ones like Recents. Press the thumbnail lightly and quickly drag it across. If you long press or wait, the photo will open and a popup with options (Copy, Share, Favorite etc.) will come up. I have edited the original answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, for clarifying, MacEater.  I think I will live with the lack of functionality, as it is not worth creating and managing an album for me.